# set non editable kendo ui mvvm grid value with code

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that is bound with kendo ui MVVM,
and i have a few columns that are not editable for the user but i still need to be able to update them from code,
But when i try to update a non editable column its just not working.

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
            entries: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "EntryId",
                        fields: {
                            EntryId: { editable: false, defaultValue: 0, },
                        }
                    },
                },
            }),

    ...
```

this wont work

```
 vm.set('EntryId',[new id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround

```
vm.EntryId = [new id];
vm.trigger('change')
```